# CodeMaid alternative for Sublime Text 3

Tags: code-beautification, sublime-text

I use Sublime Text 3 as my primary code editor. I'm looking for a plug-in for automatic code formatting (auto indentation, fix curly braces, etc.) and function sorting/reordering, and other cleanup.

In Visual Studio, I use the [CodeMaid plugin](http://www.codemaid.net/), and I'm happy with it. Does anyone know of a Sublime Text plugin that has similar functions/features?

Comment: What language(s) do you require support for?

Answer (score 3):

I like the [SublimeAStyleFormatter](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter) plugin for [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It works with C/C++/C#/Java source code files.

There are a couple methods you can use to install it (all of which are detailed in [the readme](http://www.sublimetext.com/)) but I recommend the Package Control method as very easy.

There are quite a few options. You'd probably be most interested in:

- `indent`
- `indent-spaces`
- and there are [lots more](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter/blob/master/options_default.json) - I don't know what all of them do since I rarely use C family languages so I haven't had much need for experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

Editor [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) is free, is has also AStyle-based plugin to format code (C, C++, Java, C#).

Plugin is named "AStyle Format", you find it in the Addon Manager list. It has config file with text like

`--indent=spaces --style=java`